# How do I set the maximum database size when using Entity Framework?

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework, sql-server-ce

I am using Entity Framework and SQL CE 4.0 with my WPF application. How do I set the maximum database size in accordance with this article, http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sqlservercompact/archive/2007/06/13/the-story-of-max-database-size-connection-string-parameter.aspx which states:

> we don't always grow to 4 GB, it is not wise to allocate shared memory
>   to accommodate all page entries/references to support 4 GB.

Currently, I get the following error when trying to add new data:

```
The database file is larger than the configured maximum database size.
```

However, the DB is only reaching close to 256MB, which is in line with the article in the link above.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
SqlCeConnectionFactory sqlCeConnection = 
    new SqlCeConnectionFactory("System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0", 
    "", "Max Database Size=4000;Persist Security Info=False;");
DbDatabase.DefaultConnectionFactory = sqlCeConnection;
DbDatabase.SetInitializer(new SampleData());
```

Where the third parameter is the connection string and you change the parameter `Max Database Size` otherwise it defaults to 256MB.

Answer (score 6):

Alternatively using the `app.config`:

```xml
<entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
        <parameters>
            <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0"/>
            <parameter value=""/>
            <parameter value="Max Database Size=4000"/>
        </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
```